# Understanding "divides" notation (aka "|") in "d | (k,n)"

Tags: elementary-number-theory, notation, divisibility

I'm wondering what the notation under the sigma symbol means:

[image: Summation with notation in question.]

I understand that d | k means that d divides k. However, I am unsure of what d | (k,n) means. Does this mean d divides both k and n? Or is there some function (k,n) performed with k and n?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: I think $(k,n)$ is the GCD of k and n, and $d$ divides it.

Comment: @SS_C4 And, of course, to say that $d$ divides the greatest common divisor of $k$ and $n$ is the same as saying that $d$ divides both $k$ and $n.$

Comment: @bof Yes, I agree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means $d$ divides the HCF of $k,n$.HCF of $k,n$ is represented by $(k,n)$.

Note-Indirectly it means,$d$ divides both $k$ and $n$.

Comment: Where "HCF" = highest common factor, better known as greatest common divisor. So, of course, the OP was correct in guessing that it means $d$ divides both $k$ and $n$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So, to understand its usage under the sigma symbol further, I can only choose values of d such that d divides the highest common factor of k and n?

Comment: @jbernazzani Yes...you are correct...